# Writing ANTLR4 grammar rules for 3 primitive data types: INT (integer), FLOAT, and CHAR (character)

Tags: java, antlr, grammar

Below is my ANTLR grammar which I made, but I don't know when I am checking from JAVA I getting some error.

MY Basic AIM is to Establish ANTLR grammar rules for 3 primitive data types: INT (integer), FLOAT, and CHAR (character). BasForCCal will have more data types lat

```
grammar BasForCCAL;
// Vivek Mishra
@header {
package basforccal;
import java.util.HashMap;
}

@lexer::header{
package basforccal;
}

@members{
        String programName;
        boolean errors = false;
        HashMap memory = new HashMap();



        public void checkName(String endName){
            if(!endName.equals(programName)){
            System.out.println("Wrong Program name in end of the program");
            }
        }
}

program : start programbody end;
start   :'PROGRAM' ID {programName = $ID.text ; System.out.println("Checking program :"+$ID.text);};

programbody
    :   devcar*;

devcar  :   initInt var1|
                intFloat var1|
                intChar var1 ;


initInt :   'INT'
        ;

intFloat
    :   'FLOAT'
    ;

intChar:     'CHAR';     
end
        : 'END' ID '.' {checkName($ID.text);};

var1    : idname (',' var1)* ;

idname  :    ID {Integer v = (Integer)memory.get($ID.text);
                    if(v!=null) 
                        {System.err.println("Error: "+$ID.text+" already defined line:"+$ID.getLine());}
                    else
                        {memory.put($ID.text,new Integer('1'));}
                    }
        ;
```

This is the error which I am getting in  parser file.

```
Error:(391, 46) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable memory
  location: class basforccal.BasForCCALParser
Error:(395, 50) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable memory
  location: class basforccal.BasForCCALParser
```

Comment: What is the name of your grammars filename? is it in lowercase?

Comment: @Har No, It's in Capital "BasForCCAL.g"

Comment: Where's the definition of `ID`? (I don't know if it's relevant, but without it it's impossible to compile your program.)

Comment: ... To the extent that I was able to compile this program (removing the `@lexer:header` block and giving `ID` a definition, I was unable to reproduce. The only diagnostic I received was a deprecation notice for `new Integer('1')`. Please update this question with a [mre].